# Unsuccessful connection on ssh to the subordinate nodes of a cluster

Tags: linux, ssh, connection, out, timed

Executing start of services on the subordinate nodes of a cluster by means of the following command:

```
hadoop@one:/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin$. ./start-all.sh
```

not the first time I receive result

```
starting namenode, logging to /export/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop--namenode-one.out
192.168.1.10: starting datanode, logging to /export/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-myhost2.out
192.168.1.11: ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.11 port 22: Connection timed out
192.168.1.5: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /export/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-one.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /export/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop--jobtracker-one.out
192.168.1.10: starting tasktracker, logging to /export/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-myhost2.out
192.168.1.11: ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.11 port 22: Connection timed out
```

How do I fix the error below:

```
ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection timed out

hadoop@one: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin$ ssh -vvv 192.168.1.10
Sun_SSH_1.5, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x1000004f
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
debug1: ssh_connect: needpriv 0 
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.10 [192.168.1.10] port 22
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.10 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.10 port 22: Connection timed out
```

What to do to correct an error?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have edited your post to make your question more clear.

Comment: +1 @Brian. This is how newbies ahould be treated

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sshd daemon running on your machine? Your OS might come with ssh, but in order to start sshd daemon, you need to install ssh completely. By complete I mean :

> ssh : The command we use to connect to remote machines - the client.
>
> sshd : The daemon that runs on the server and allows clients to
>   connect to this server.

Also, make sure there is no issue with port 22. If you still face some issue try ssh with -v switch to get the complete trace.

```
ssh -v myhost2
```

You can go [here](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-setup-and-configure-ssh-on-ubuntu.html#.Uaj4XkAW38s) for a detailed explanation of ssh.

Comment: hadoop@one: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin$ ssh -v 192.168.1.10
 Sun_SSH_1.5, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x1000004f
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
 debug1: ssh_connect: needpriv 0 
 debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.10 [192.168.1.10] port 22
 debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.10 port 22: Connection timed out
 ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.10 port 22: Connection timed out

@Tariq